# Error Insert PHP OO Sql Server sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql-server

Pessoal essa Classe ta me dando um trabalho confesso a vocês que não vejo erro aqui, ja vi no php.net creio que estou seguindo todas as logicas e sintaxes. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar a resolver esse problema fico muito agradecido.

```
<?php
include_once 'Conexao.class.php';
class Administrador {
    private $Nome;
    private $Endereco;
    private $Telefone;
    private $Conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Conn = new Conexao();
    }

    public function inserir($Nome, $Endereco, $Telefone){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO CADPES (NOME, ENDERECO, NUMERO)VALUES(?,?,?)";
        $params = array($this->Nome, $this->Endereco, $this->Telefone); 
        $query = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn->Conectar(), $sql, $params) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

}
```

classe adm e agora minha classe Conexao

```
<?php

class Conexao{
    private $Localhost  = 'NOTEBOOK101010\SQLEXPRESS';
    private $User  = 'sa';
    private $Pass  = '';
    private $Database  = 'ALISON';
    private $Con = null;
    private $Coninfo = null;

    function __construct() {
        //return $this->Coninfo;
    }

    public function Conectar(){
        $this->Localhost;
        $this->User;
        $this->Pass;
        $this->Database;

        $this->Con = array("Database" => $this->Localhost, "UID" => $this->User, "PWD" => $this->Pass);
        $this->Coninfo = sqlsrv_connect($this->Database, $this->Con);
        return $this->Coninfo;

        if($this->Coninfo){
            echo "Conectou";
        }else{
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_error(), true));
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o Conectar() não está conseguindo conectar e retorna um false.
Retorno do sqlsrv_connect:

```
A connection resource. If a connection cannot be successfully opened, FALSE is returned.
```

E detalhe:

```
return $this->Coninfo;

    if($this->Coninfo){
        echo "Conectou";
    }else{
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_error(), true));
    }
```

Esse trexo de código não faz sentido, pois você está verificando depois do return. Logo nunca vai chegar no if.

E também é bom tratar o retorno antes de usar ele direto no método pois se ele retornar outra coisa se nao uma resource ele vai dar erro, e não queremos que de erro npé?

Comment: mudei o return como vc falou coloquei ele na condição if agora ele trás outro erro +/ vc ja tinha dado a dica. Mas como resolvo? sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Comment: Na verdade você tem que colocar algo como "echo $this->Coninfo;" depois um var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());die;  para pdoer ver o que está retornando no COnifo e se deu algum erro. A partir dai vc ve oq precisa mudar para sua conexão funcionar

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Con = array("Database" => $this->Database, "UID" => $this->User, "PWD" => $this->Pass);
$this->Coninfo = sqlsrv_connect($this->Localhost, $this->Con);
```

Droga esse era erro que estava dando, troquei o Database pelo Localhost confundi na hora dei var_dump é vi.